# Add Ionic 3 Plugin from Github Fork

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to add a plugin from a github fork of the InAppBrowser. [This is the fork I want to use](https://github.com/al1lhomme/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser). I know how to add the plugin. I simply use Ionic Cordova plugin add https://github.com/al1lhomme/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

But how can I import it to the modules.ts? I think it is necessary to add it to npm correct? I think I have to install the npm module to import it in my modules.ts file.
I tried to use cordova.plugins.InAppBrowser but it doesn't work.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Yes, you have to run `npm` command to add it to your module.ts

Comment: but which one? The npm install command of the main repo? Or from the fork? Think the fork has no npm command because its not added to npm.

Comment: I Think the from the main repo.

Answer (score 0):

You never add the Plugin to the Module. What you add to the `Modules.ts` is the native Wrapper from Ionic. You can use Plugins without this Wrapper, but they are developed for an easier use. I don't know if they work with Forks, normally they are developed to work with the original plugin.

So try to just add the Plugin via

> ionic cordova plugin add *path_to_fork*

And use it without the Wrapper, as described in the Plugins Read Me